# IE conditional comments aren't working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin, conditional-comments

I'm using IE (Internet Explorer) conditional comments to fix margin issues on IE, but for some reason its not working and I am unable to fix it.

CSS code (embedded in conditional comment):

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <style>
.right_header_form{
    float: right;
    margin: -360px 50px 0;
    width: 240px;
    height: auto;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 21px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #FFF;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.right_form {
    float: right;
    margin: -320px 50px 0;
    width: 240px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

My original CSS code for all other browsers:

```
.right_header_form{
    float: right;
    margin: -390px 50px 0;
    width: 240px;
    height: auto;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 21px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #FFF;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.right_form {
    float: right;
    margin: -350px 50px 0;
    width: 240px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

As you can see, the margin is different between each code to the other. As I said, it doesn't work but it seems like the code is valid.

**Q:** How can I change CSS code for IE using only conditional comments?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Well, I used margin so it's a bit problem with IE browser.

Comment: Which version of IE. IE11 does not recognise conditional comments.

Comment: I think this could well be because of adding padding and width to the same container. IE uses a different box model: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200612/internet_explorer_and_the_css_box_model/

Comment: I think margin is not the problem.. please create some screenshot etc to show what is the problem..

Comment: Probably, Sigma is right and its a [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) issue. Adding a doctype will make IE switch to content-box model.

Comment: @hardy http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/1673/b0be.png <- Fire Fox
http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/1323/6xhq.png <- IE

Comment: @Oriol It's location problem, not size.

Comment: @Paulie_D IE 10 and lower

Comment: Aha...in fact IE10 does not support conditional comments either. Something else must be wrong if you are seeing difference in browsers

Comment: Problem seems to be in left side.. not right.. add left side code.

Comment: @Oriol http://jsfiddle.net/NxqLk/embedded/result/

Comment: @Paulie_D http://jsfiddle.net/NxqLk/embedded/result/ Sorry for all the comments, the system pervents me to multiple notification you.

Comment: Probably it is both: a box sizing issue (no doctype? xml prolog? and IE gets in quirks mode) and looking in IE 10 or above which removed IE conditional comments all together.

Comment: @Sigma So whats the solution? what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I have to see the original code. JS fiddle adds a html 5 doctype by default. And which IE version are you debugging in.

Comment: They're called Conditional Comments, not IE Hacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!--[if IE]>
        <style>
            .right_header_form{
                margin: 20px 0 0;
            }
            .right_form {
                margin: 20px 0 0;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Checked your PHP code from mediafire.
Your styles for IE are overwritten because the IE conditional is first in the code. Should be first style.css. CSS precedence.

Should be:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <style>
            .right_header_form{
                margin: 20px 0 0;
            }
            .right_form {
                margin: 20px 0 0;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: It didn't changed a thing, In Firefox its working but IE not.

Comment: You also had one error in your html. The alt attribute is required for images.

Comment: @Sigma: That's not an "error", because HTML has no real errors; it shouldn't affect this problem. But it's non-standard to omit the `alt`, surely.

Comment: Using negative margins can complicate the rendering of a lay-out. Maybe try to avoid this all together. And use padding on relative containers to add vertical spacing or top margins with positive values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
margin: -390px 50px 0;
```

Basically, you guess that the height of `.main_form` is `390px`, so you make `.right_header_form` go `390px` upwards.

That's bad.

Before coding a page, you must think a good design.

In this case, make two columns and place them one next to other **floating the first one** (and second one optionally). And place the headers inside each column.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Conditional Comments only work for INTERNET EXPLORER 9 and LOWER, from IE10 and bigger it has been disabled.

What I recommend is that you put your IE CSS in another css file called iestyle.css and call it like this :

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”iestyle.css”/>
<![endif]-->
```

This has  to work,

Best of luck.

**PS: ALSO**

You can use conditional comments in your HTML to apply different CSS classes or IDs to elements that you can then target with CSS.

Works something like this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <div id="content" class="ie">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
  <div id="content">
<![endif]-->
```

What this does is for `IE` it adds a class "ie" that you specify in your CSS and when it is NOT IE `!IE` it does not add that class.